# Android Generate Signed APK Error?

Tags: android, gradle, apk

My first Android project is finish. I want to load Google Play.
when I make  **build -> Generate Signed APK** give error android studio.

> For Gradle-based projects, the signing configuration should be
>   specified in the Gradle build scripts.See the Gradle User Guide for
>   more info."

I tried to sign configs as this sample

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("mykeystore")
            storePassword "mypassword"  
            keyAlias "my alias"
            keyPassword "mykeypassword"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

But I dont know mykeystore and my password and other infos.

```
release {
            storeFile file("mykeystore")  -> what is mykeystore ?
            storePassword "mypassword"    -> what is mypassword ?
            keyAlias "my alias"           -> what is myalias ?
            keyPassword "mykeypassword"      -> what is mykeypassword ?
        }
```

I cant build apk my project. This is my first project.
I use android studio 2.0.11 and mac os x lion.

Please help. Sorry bad english. 
Thanks.

Comment: The graddle code you have is correct, to obtain a keystore file, password, alias and key password, follow the instructions in this guide to generate a keystore file. http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

Comment: Android Studio update 0.3.0 and my problem is fixed